# Android Fragment ViewModel databinding not updating UI even though lifecycleOwner is set

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I want to use a `ViewModel` with a Databinding to disable a Checkbox when a Button is clicked, but the UI won't update unless the fragment is destroyed and recreated.

There seem to be many similar questions, but the ones that are most similar seem to all be solved by setting `binding.lifecycleOwner`, which I've already done.

fragment_checkbox_databinding.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".CheckboxDatabindingFragment">
    
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type=".CheckboxDatabindingFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="@{viewModel.checkboxEnabled}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.startClicked()}" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

CheckboxDatabindingFragment.kt:

```java
class CheckboxDatabindingFragment() : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: CheckboxDatabindingFragmentViewModel

    private var _binding: FragmentCheckboxDatabindingBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CheckboxDatabindingFragmentViewModel::class.java )
        
        _binding = FragmentCheckboxDatabindingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner // androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        
        return binding.root
    }
    ...
}
```

CheckboxDatabindingFragmentViewModel.kt:

```java
class CheckboxDatabindingFragmentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var checkboxEnabled = true

    fun startClicked() {
        checkboxEnabled = false
    }
}
```

I know I could easily carry out this functionality by manually getting the checkbox view in `CheckboxDatabindingFragment.kt` and setting the `isEnabled` property, but that defeats the purpose of the DataBinding.

I need the fragment, not the activity, to be the owner, so how can I get the fragment UI to update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Problem:

> var checkboxEnabled = true

The top statement creates a **non-observable** boolean, so no changes on that variable can be observed and submitted to the layout through the life cycle owner (which in your case is the fragment).

[But, as per documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#setlifecycleowner)

> Sets the LifecycleOwner that should be used for observing changes of
> LiveData in this binding. If a LiveData is in one of the binding
> expressions and no LifecycleOwner is set, the LiveData will not be
> observed and updates to it will not be propagated to the UI.

So, using `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` alone is not enough to publish the changes to the layout through databinding, but also you've to use observable objects that can be observed by the lifeCycleOwner and eventually publish any changes on them to the layout via the DataBinding.

##### Solution:

To solve this you need to change the `checkboxEnabled` to an observable:

**Option 1: use [ObservableBoolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableBoolean):**

```
class CheckboxDatabindingFragmentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val checkboxEnabled = ObservableBoolean(true)

    fun startClicked() {
        checkboxEnabled.set(false)
    }
}
```

**Option 2: use [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData):**

```
class CheckboxDatabindingFragmentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val checkboxEnabled = MutableLiveData(true)

    fun startClicked() {
        checkboxEnabled.value = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This was such a clear and helpful answer, thanks!